# How to stop dots being cut off at edge of grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple grid of dots which I make with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Add blue dots
for x in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
        plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', s=20)  # Adjust the size (s) as needed
       

# Customize plot
ax = plt.gca()  

ax.set(xlim=(0, 9), ylim=(0, 9), xlabel='', ylabel='')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 9.01, 1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 9.01, 1))
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
ax.grid()
```

This looks like:

[image]

The dots on the edge of the grid are cut off. How can I show them complete without changing anything else about the picture? I don't want to extend the grid lines for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try turning-off the [Clipping](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/artist_api.html#clipping) by setting [`clip_on`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on) to `False` :

```
for x in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
        plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', s=20, clip_on=False) # << here
```

[image]